# How to create xpath for dynamic data table?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image]I need to click on first row of the data table.But this data table will vary always according to the user.How I can create xpath for those kind of dynamic elements?

```
<div id="periodAccordion">
<h3 id="p5-header" onclick="periodOnClick('5','2016')">Period 5</h3>
<div id="p5">
<h3 id="p3-header" onclick="periodOnClick('3','2016')">Period 3</h3>
<div id="p3">
<h3 id="p2-header" onclick="periodOnClick('2','2016')">Period 2</h3>
<div id="p2">
<h3 id="p1-header" onclick="periodOnClick('1','2016')">Period 1</h3>
<div id="p1">
<h3 id="p10-header" onclick="periodOnClick('10','2015')">Period 10</h3>
<div id="p10">
<h3 id="p8-header" onclick="periodOnClick('8','2015')">Period 8</h3>
<div id="p8">
</div>
```

Here I need to create xpath for first element.its attibutes is:

```
<h3 id="p5-header" onclick="periodOnClick('5','2016')">Period 5</h3>
<div id="p5">
```

How can i create xpath for this element?Here all the elements will vary when i login with a other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you always want to select the first row, use the below xpath:

```
//h3[contains(@id,'header') and contains(@onclick,'periodOnClick') ][1]
```

hope this will help you and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following xpath to select the first `h3` :

```
//div[@id='periodAccordion']/h3
```

if you need for the first `div` from the main div, then:

```
//div[@id='periodAccordion']/div
```

If you need only the firs one then you can use:

```
//div[@id='periodAccordion']/h3[1]
```

Comment: When I use above xpaths, it is selecting whole table.(i.e this is selecting Period 5,Period 3,Period 2, Period 1, etc).Because all tables are placed under same header and div.

Comment: Yes, but your find method will return only the first element found. You have method to find all elements or find one element, the second one will return only one element, the first found.